# Conditional probability given multiple independent events

Tags: probability

I am interested in finding the conditional probability $P(A|E_1,E_2,...,E_n)$ where the $E_i$ are mutually independent events. I know only $P(A)$ and $P(A|E_i)$.

Is this possible? If so, how? If not, what information is missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(A\mid \bigcap_i E_i)
& = \frac{\mathsf P(\bigcap_i E_i\mid A)\cdot\mathsf P(A)}{P(\bigcap_i E_i)}
\\[1ex]
& = \frac{\mathsf P(\bigcap_i E_i\mid A)\cdot \mathsf P(A)}{\prod_i \mathsf P(E_i)}
\end{align}$

To proceed further you require a guarantee of *conditional independence*.   That is: $\mathsf P(\bigcap_i E_i\mid A) = \prod_i\mathsf P(E_i\mid A)$

However, mutually independent events $\{E_1, E_2, \ldots E_n\}$ are *not necessarily* mutually, conditionally independent given event $A$.

Comment: Conditional independence took me awhile to grok. An example helps: let P(G|I,D) be the probability that a student gets a grade of G = {A,B,C,D,F} on an exam conditioned on their intellegence I and the exam difficulty D. Clearly I and D are independent *until* you have the evidence of their grade G; Once you know the grade, I and D are no longer indepedent (i.e., if the student got an F and they are really smart, then you know something about how difficult the exam was).

Comment: Seems to be contradicting this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568029/express-multiple-conditional-probability-in-terms-of-single-conditional-probabil

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya Indeed, it is.  Can you see why?  Do you agree?